# TextBox event that will Clear User input

Tags: vb.net, events, textbox

please am working on an Annual Crop Cashflow Calculator like an Excel
i have 3 text boxes.
textbox22 textbox31 and textbox71
if i multiply textbox22 by textbox31 it shows in textbox71
but the problem is i need an event jus like excel after calculating and user goes back to empty either textbox31 or textbox22 the answer in texbox71 should be empty...
but with what i have here d previous answer will still be there until user inputs another entry

solution please
below is my code

```
Private Sub TextBox71_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox22.TextChanged, TextBox31.TextChanged
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox22.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox31.Text) Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox22.Text) OrElse Not IsNumeric(TextBox31.Text) Then Exit Sub
    TextBox71.Text = CDbl(TextBox22.Text) * CDbl(TextBox31.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to consider giving your text boxes some more descriptive names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add code to the [`Enter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx) event that runs whenever the user enters a `TextBox`.

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_Enter(sender as object, e as EventArgs)
    MyTextBox.Clear
    SomeOtherTextBox.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh yes, I've been in the land of WPF for the last few years, my WinForms has gotten fuzzy.  Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Please Explain More, if Possible Draft the Code for me... Am New in WPF